# How to reduce motion video file size and how to auto-delete old files

Tags: raspbian, video, raspbian-jessie, motion

What do I change in motion.conf to reduce saved video size besides changing size of the video?

I'm currently getting about 1.2MB per minute (with emulatemotion on) of film. Using msmpeg as encoder, tried changing the bit rate (default 500k, to 2,3,400k) with no result.

Also, is there a way I could auto-delete the old video files, say keeping only the newest 100 files?

Comment: Ae you doing this via command line or a script?

Comment: bash. Want to keep only the newest 100 files IF say, the folder size exceeds 1GB

Comment: Share the relevent part of your script and tag your question with bash. Do you have a Pi 3? Have you looked at ffmpeg or the jessie version called avconv?